# django: Translation with variables inside

Tags: django

I have the following piece of code:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
task = _('You have %s friends') %(c1.task)
// This is translation
#: compositions/views.py:69
#, fuzzy, python-format
msgid "You have %s friends"
msgstr "У вас %s друга"
```

But for some reason this msgstr does not work...

Comment: Does i18n work without variables otherwise? What's the results in this case?

Comment: Yes, it works without variables. So I guess it's something about my mistakes making translation

Comment: Both, the code in the question and the code in the answer worked for me and helped me to get variables into my translated texts.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try using string placeholders - from the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/):

> The strings you pass to _() or ugettext() can take placeholders,
> specified with Python’s standard named-string interpolation syntax.
> Example:

```
def my_view(request, m, d):
    output = _('Today is %(month)s %(day)s.') % {'month': m, 'day': d}
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Applying this to your example, you'd get:

```
task = _('You have %(num_friends)s friends') % {'num_friends': c1.task}
```

Comment: That's what the OP is doing, the difference is that you're using named params and he's not. Django specifically states that if you have exactly one placeholder, you do not require it to be named.